# laravel echo listen the socket? not the variable?

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-5.6, laravel-echo, socket.io-redis

queue.blade.php

```
   Echo.channel('everyone')
            .listen('Queue_number', function (e) {
                 console.log('e='+e);
                 console.log('e keys='+Object.keys(e));
                 console.log('socket='+e.socket);
                 console.log('city='+e.city);
                 console.log('p_id='+e.p_id);
                 console.log('message='+e.message);
                 console.log('s_number='+e.s_number);
```

app/Events/Queue_number.php

```
class Queue_number  implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $message;
    public $s_number;
    public $city;
    public $p_id;
    public function __construct($message,$s_number,$city,$p_id)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        //$this->s_number = $s_number;
        $this->s_number = '1234';
        $this->city = '236';
        $this->p_id = $p_id;

    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('everyone');
    }
```

controller

```
   public function queue_add(Request $request)
    {
        $message = $request->validate(['message'=>'required']);
        $s_number=$request->name;
        $city=$request->city;
        $p_id=$request->p_id;

        broadcast(new Queue_number($message['message'],$s_number,$city,$p_id));
//->toOthers()

return response()->json(['status'=>'success','message'=>$message['message'],'s_number'=>$s_number,'city'=>$city,'p_id'=>$p_id]);
    }
```

I received the console from the Events Queue_number.php

```
       e=[object Object]
63:615 e keys=message,s_number,socket
63:616 socket=null
63:617 city=undefined
63:618 p_id=undefined
63:619 message=1
63:620 s_number=1234
```

I don't know why the message and s_number is right but the others like city and  p_id is null, undefined?

and the object key is message,s_number,socket

why shows 'socket' the key word?

how to fix the problem to get these two variables $city and $p_id?

thanks any helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the stupid answer
whenever change the code
You must restart the
1.laravel-echo-server start
2.php artisan queue:work

and everything is fine~